# Lightining record page

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have lightining record page details,I have a section named as fullfill management section that i have to move from left side panel to the right side panel.
How we can achieve this in lightining?

Do we have to make layout changes or modify the lightning component code?

if code is requried, please refer some link(s)?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe your best bet would be to go with a Custom [Lightning Page Template Component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder_template_component.htm), which support record pages, app pages, and the Home page.

You can define the sections in your page alongside the drag and dropable parts.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a standard page layout and the standard record detail component, you will not be able to move a particular section from the standard page layout to the area specified.

If your record detail page is built with a custom lightning component, you can then have a separate lightning component only consisting of the fields from Fulfillment Management section and have that component embedded on the region where you want it to be displayed.